# Splitting data into disjoint sets

Tags: r, disjoint-sets

I've a matrix (200x3) which i want to split into 3 random chosen **disjoint** sets. How can i realize it?

I tried to do it via sample method but sample method accepts just vectors and output is not really part of my matrix.

Thus, it is my matrix:

```
          X1           X2     Y
1   -3.381342627  1.037658397 0
2    3.329754336  1.964180648 0
3    1.760001645 -3.414310545 0
4   -2.450315854 -2.299838395 0
5   -3.334593596  0.069458604 0
6    1.708921101 -2.333932571 0
7   -2.650506645  0.348985289 0
8   -2.935307106 -0.402072990 0
9    2.867566309 -3.217712074 0
10   3.617603017  1.956535384 0
```

And i want to split in 3 sets like this: (row-numbers have to be random chosen). And i want to able to give the size of sets. For example in this case, 4 4 2.

```
9    2.867566309 -3.217712074 0
3    1.760001645 -3.414310545 0
1   -3.381342627  1.037658397 0
2    3.329754336  1.964180648 0


5   -3.334593596  0.069458604 0
8   -2.935307106 -0.402072990 0
4   -2.450315854 -2.299838395 0
6    1.708921101 -2.333932571 0


10   3.617603017  1.956535384 0
7   -2.650506645  0.348985289 0
```

Comment: must the 3 random sets be of the same dimensions?

Comment: Yes, they should all have 3 columns. thus a matrix

Comment: and the rows will be equal? 200 is not divisible by 3 without a remainder

Comment: I'm not positive what you want in terms of the number of rows in each set. Do you want a function that lets you specify the sizes or do you want them as equally sized as possible or are the sizes static?

Comment: my aim was to split data to different sets like training sets, test sets and so on.

Comment: use `sample` to shuffle all row indices, then split that any way you like and select from original matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way,

```
# a matrix with 3 columns
m <- matrix(runif(300), ncol=3)

# split into a list of dataframes (of course, you can convert back to matrices)
m_split <- split(as.data.frame(m), sample(1:3, size=nrow(m), replace=TRUE))

# count nr of rows
sapply(m_split, nrow)

# Or, as in the comment below, split by given number of rows per split
nsplit <- c(30,30,40)
m_split2 <- split(as.data.frame(m), rep(1:3, nsplit))
```

Comment: THanks! how can i give the number of rows that each splitted dataframe has?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it (may be not best way but solved) as follows:

```
nsamples= nrow(data)
//first take a random numbers; %40 of total number of samples
sampleInd = sample(nsamples,0.4*nsamples)
//construct first set via the half of taken indexes
valInd = sampleInd[1:floor(length(sampleInd)/2)]
valSet = dat[valInd,]
//other half
testInd = sampleInd[(floor(length(sampleInd)/2)+1):length(sampleInd)]
testSet = dat[testInd,]
//unused %60
trainSet = dat[-sampleInd,]
ntrain = nrow(trainSet)
```

Procents can be changed as you wish. The idea is thus dividing the matrix via function sample in terms of indices. Then using indices to take the actual matrices.

Answer (score 0):

The idea I mentioned in the comments:

```
# shuffle rows
rows = sample(nrow(m))

# split any way you like, e.g. 4/4/rest
rows.split = split(rows, c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4), rep(3,nrow(m) - 4 - 4)))

# subset the matrix
lapply(rows.split, function(x) m[x,])
```